# Return value of $q promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
//controller pour connection to API
.controller('LoginConnect', ['$scope', 'connecting',
function($scope,connecting){
    $scope.user = {};
    var users = $scope.user;


    $scope.connect = function (users) {

      var log = $scope.user.login;
      var pass = $scope.user.password;
      var mydata = {};
      connecting.login(log,pass,mydata);
      $scope.datab = mydata;
    };
  }
])

  //factory pour aller chercher le token
.factory('connecting', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
      var token;
      var ConnectingFactory = {};
      ConnectingFactory.login = function(log,pass){

       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/login.php",
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           transformRequest: function(obj) {
               var str = [];
               for(var p in obj)
               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
               return str.join("&");
           },
           data: {login: log, password: pass}
           })
       .success(function(result){
          deferred.resolve(result);
          var promise = deferred.promise;
          promise.then(function(result){
          var  mydata = result["data"];
            }
          );
         })
       };
       return ConnectingFactory;
}]);
;
```

Hi, I'm new in AngularJS, and I want to know how can I send data I received from API into a global variable and inject it into a $scope. In this example, I want to send my result from $q and show it in my view.

Comment: Great explanation on how to use "$q" efficiently: http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
ConnectingFactory.login = function(log,pass){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({...}).success(function(data){
           deferred.resolve(data);
       });

  return deferred.promise;
}

connecting.login(log,pass).then(function(data){
   $scope.datab = data; // your recived data
});
```

You should also implement the error of the http response like:

```
.error(function(data){
   deffered.reject(data);
});
```

Your code in the success-callback is not the best one. Basicly it does work, but you will have some timing issues (and it does not make much sense).

Comment: Yes i received data but not those i expected, i should received data from the request i sent in my $http and here i received data without use my function .login() so when i called my function .login() nothing is refresh and i don t have the data i expect. Do you understand what am i saying ?

Comment: You want to recieve the data, which you will get from your http call. This data will be in your success-callback (which is 'result' in your code). This will be resolved by the promise. After that, your login() function will return a promise, which you enter with login(...).then(function(THIS_IS_THE_RESPONSE){});. You need the 'then'-function, its used by the promised. http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: Exactly ! and i want to send my variable "result" into my controller so i can re-use it as i want

Comment: Exactly! This 'result' variable is IN the .then function. connecting.login(log,pass).then(function(data){
   console.log(data); // THIS IS YOUR RESPONSE OF THE LOGIN SUCCESS CALLBACK
});. the passed variable naming has not to be the same. 'data' = 'result', its just a naming